# Stochastic process over the expected time of tasting all $N$ dishes of a restaurant

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

**Exercise :**

> Every time you visit a certain restaurant, you choose randomly one of its $N$ dishes. What is the expected number of visits you have to make to the restaurant until you taste all of its dishes ?

**Attempt / Question :**

Picking randomly one of its $N$ dishes, obviously means that you have $1/N$ chance of picking every dish. Now, each time you visit the restaurant and you pick a different dish than all the others, the probability of picking a different dish again becomes smaller, as $1/(N-n)$, where $n$ is the number of different dishes you've picked.

Now, I know that expected time (hitting time) problems of such can be solved by modelling your process into a *Boundary Value Problem (BVP)* of the form (which will give an answer to the expected time $\mathbb{E}[T_A | X_0 = x] = \mathbb{E}_x[T_A]$) :

$$\begin{cases} Lg(x) = -1, x \notin A \\ g(x) = 0, x \in A\end{cases}$$

if $A \subset \mathbb{X}$ and $T_A = \inf\{k \geq 0 : X_k \in A\}$ the time of the first arrival at $A$.

**On this particular problem, though, I find myself stuck on trying to model it into an boundary value problem**.

I would really appreciate any explanation on how to proceed.

Comment: This is the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ be the expected time to sample the remaining $n$ dishes, given that you have sampled $N-n$ dishes already. We are interested in calculating $f(N)$.

It is easy to see that $f$ satisfies the recursion

\begin{align*}
f(n) &= \frac{N-n}{N}[f(n)+1] + \frac{n}{N}[f(n-1)+1] \\
&= 1 + \frac{N-n}{N}f(n) + \frac{n}{N}f(n-1).
\end{align*}

We also have the boundary condition $f(0)=0$. We can simplify the equation above to find

$$f(n) = \frac{N}{n} + f(n-1).$$

This gives us that

$$ f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{N}{k}, $$

so that

$$ f(N)= \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{N}{k}. $$